# How to add a caption to an image in Confluence Ondemand?

Tags: confluence, ondemand

I've inserted an image in a Confluence page. There does not seem to be an option to add a caption to provide a short explanation of the image.

I found a link - https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Displaying+Images that "explains" how to add a caption.

**Add a caption to an image:**

- Choose Effects in the image properties panel and choose the Instant Camera image effect.
  Save the page.
- Choose Tools > Attachments to go to the 'Attachments' view of the page.
- Choose **Properties** next to the image file.
- Add a **comment** to the attachment. The text in your comment will appear as the image caption.

When I follow the instructions, I do not see a Properties for the image or a comment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My workaround is to add a 1x2 cells table that holds the image in the upper cell and the caption in the lower one.

Edit:
Since June 2021 the Confluence cloud editor offers a way to add text as a basic caption beneath any image.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Olivia Gajadhar's answer, Atlassian has added a workaround of adding a comment to the "Instant Camera" effect; see the [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/display-files-and-images-245827130.html) for more details.

Unfortunately Atlassian hasn't got their act together and still haven't implemented captions for real. See Confluence bug [CONF-2584](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-2584).

Comment: good idea but doesnt work as well, cause the text can be really tiny if the thumbnail is not large enough :(

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question is quite old, and it doesn't look like anyone has answered it, so I hope that I can help.

I'm using Confluence Cloud (formerly Confluence Ondemand), and the way that I add a caption is that instead of clicking on the *Instant Camera* under *Effects*, I click on *Title.* From there, I enter the text that I want into the caption field. When you save your edits, the caption should appear after you hover your pointer over the image.

Comment: I don't consider that a caption.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a text above the image and centering it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Garret Wilson in his answer, Atlassian have a work item to add proper image captions: [CONFCLOUD-2584](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFCLOUD-2584).

They appear to be finally working on it.  As at May 2021 it still hasn't been released.   However, the last update, in mid December 2020, was that it should go live early in fiscal year 2021 (presumably that means sometime after April 2021).

So keep an eye on that work item and you may see image captions go live some time in 2021.